Error: NG0203 inject() must be called from an injection context and Error: NG0200: Circular dependency
Whenever I want to inject a service as DI, I get this two error.
app-insights-error-handler.ts:19 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/new RuntimeError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:216176:5) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:217224:11) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/Module.ɵɵinject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:217234:59) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/Object.SelectionHelperService_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:207754:100) [angular]
    at :4200/vendor.js:119017:33 [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/runInInjectorProfilerContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:110639:5) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:119016:9) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:118896:23) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:118905:27) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:118905:27) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:110678:36) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/ɵɵinject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:110684:59) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/inject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:110767:10) [angular]
    at :4200/main.js:9664:60 [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9062:19) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9015:9) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:9123:9 [angular]
    at :4200/vendor.js:120310:49 [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120310:30) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120624:25) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8460:23) [<root>]

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for SelectionHelperService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for SelectionHelperService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.mjs:228:11)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:9448:13)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9323:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9334:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9334:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:842:40)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:848:60)
    at inject (core.mjs:932:12)
    at three-d-viewer.component.ts:30:13
    at runInInjectionContext (core.mjs:10347:16)
    at new ThreeDViewerComponent (three-d-viewer.component.ts:29:26)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.ThreeDViewerComponent_Factory [as factory] (three-d-viewer.component.ts:49:4)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:4862:44)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:12629:27)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:12045:5)
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9062:19) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9015:9) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:9123:9 [angular]
    at :4200/vendor.js:120310:49 [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120310:30) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120624:25) [angular]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8460:23) [<root>]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8369:11) [<root>]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9489:12) [<root>]
    at :4200/machine-details/S0431Q0017/globalCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9519:21) [<root>]

This is the component which want to use a service.
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectionHelperService } from 'my-external-library';

@Component({
  selector: 'svs-three-d-viewer',
  templateUrl: './three-d-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./three-d-viewer.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ThreeDViewerComponent {
  public constructor(private readonly selectionHelperService: SelectionHelperService) {}
}

This service is from an external library in my organisation. I am not sure why this doesn't work. Actually when I create a new project and did the same, it works but for the current project Angular 16.2.12, I get the error above.
So I tried another approach with EnvironmentInjector from runInjectionContext:
@Component({
  selector: 'svs-three-d-viewer',
  templateUrl: './three-d-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./three-d-viewer.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ThreeDViewerComponent {
  public constructor(private readonly injector: EnvironmentInjector) {
    runInInjectionContext(this.injector, () => {
      inject(SelectionHelperService);
    });
  }
}

But still the same error. What is causing this error?`
In another standalone project this library and this way to inject the service was fine but I want to use this in the main project as well.
Don't know if this is relevant but this is the how the service is implemented:
Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SelectionHelperService {
  private readonly matcapHelper = new MatcapHelper();
  private materialBackups: {
    [key: number]: THREE.Material | THREE.Material[];
  } = {};
  private _highlightMaterial: Promise<THREE.Material> | undefined;
  private selections: Selection[] = [];
  private model?: SceneGraphRendererModelNode;
  private toolPathSegments: ToolPathSegmentMeshes[] = [];

  public get highlightMaterial(): Promise<THREE.Material> {
    if (!this._highlightMaterial) {
      this._highlightMaterial = this.matcapHelper.getMatcapMaterial(0xf37a27);
    }
    return this._highlightMaterial;
  }

  constructor(
    private selectionInfoService: SelectionInfoService,
    private lineMaterials: SceneGraphLineMaterialsService
  ) {
    selectionInfoService.selectedState$.subscribe((t) =>
      this.onNewSelectedState(t)
    );
  }

  public setSceneGraphRendererModel(model: SceneGraphRendererModelNode) {
    this.model = model;
    this.setToolPathSegments(model);
  }

  public setToolPathSegments(node: SceneGraphRendererModelNode) {
    this.toolPathSegments = this.getAllToolPathSegments(node);
    this.selections = [];
  }

  private onNewSelectedState(selectedState: number | undefined) {
    if (
      selectedState
        ? this.selections.some((t) => t.segmentId === selectedState)
        : this.selections.length === 0
    )
      return;

    const index = this.toolPathSegments.findIndex(
      (t) => t.segment.id === selectedState
    );
    if (index >= 0) {
      const stateIndicator = this.getStateIndicatorOfSegment(index);
      this.selectSingle(stateIndicator);
    } else {
      this.deselectAll();
    }
  }

  private getAllToolPathSegments(
    model: SceneGraphRendererModelNode
  ): ToolPathSegmentMeshes[] {
    const parentSegments = this.getToolPathSegments(model.nodeMeshSet);
    const childSegments = model.children.flatMap((t) =>
      this.getAllToolPathSegments(t)
    );
    return parentSegments.concat(childSegments);
  }

  private getToolPathSegments(
    nodeMeshes: NodeMeshSet
  ): ToolPathSegmentMeshes[] {
    return nodeMeshes.toolPath
      ? nodeMeshes.toolPath.segments.map((t) => ({
          segment: t.segment,
          meshes: this.getAllSegmentMeshes(t),
        }))
      : [];
  }

  private getAllSegmentMeshes(segmentMeshSet: SegmentMeshSet): THREE.Mesh[] {
    return segmentMeshSet.trace
      ? [segmentMeshSet.trace, segmentMeshSet.waypointIndicator]
      : [segmentMeshSet.waypointIndicator];
  }

  public async onObjectSelected(event: SelectionEvent) {
    // If we click into the void or on something that is not selectable we deselect everything.
    if (!event.selectedObject || !this.isSelectable(event.selectedObject)) {
      this.deselectAll();
    }
    // From here on we are sure to have a selectable object.
    // If there is nothing selected yet we just select the object.
    else if (!this.selections.length) {
      this.selectSingleOrSegment(event.selectedObject);
    }
    // From here on we have to deal with already selected objects.
    // If control and shift keys are pressed we extend the selection.
    else if (event.poiterEvent.shiftKey && event.poiterEvent.ctrlKey) {
      this.extendSelection(event.selectedObject);
    }

    // If only the shift key is pressed we select a range from the first selected object to the new object.
    else if (event.poiterEvent.shiftKey) {
      this.selectRange(event.selectedObject);
    }

    // If nothing else fits we again just select the object.
    else {
      this.selectSingleOrSegment(event.selectedObject);
    }

    this.sendSelected();
  }

  private sendSelected() {
    const lastIndex = this.selections.length - 1;
    const id =
      lastIndex >= 0 ? this.selections[lastIndex].segmentId : undefined;
    this.selectionInfoService.setSelectedState(id);
  }

  private deselectAll(startIndex = 0) {
    this.selections.forEach((t, i) => {
      if (i < startIndex) return;
      const target = this.getSelected(t);
      this.setHighlightOff(target);
    });
    this.selections = this.selections.filter((_, i) => i < startIndex);
  }

  private async selectSingleOrSegment(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    this.selectSingle(target);
    if (!this.isStateIndicator(target)) {
      this.selectRange(target);
    }
  }

  private async selectSingle(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    this.deselectAll();
    await this.select(target);
  }

  private async select(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    const selection = this.createSelection(target);
    if (this.selections.some((t) => t.meshId === target.id)) return;

    this.selections.push(selection);
    await this.setHighlightOn(target);
  }

  private async extendSelection(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    if (!this.selections.length) {
      this.selectSingle(target);
      return;
    }

    const rangeExtension = this.getRangeExtension(target);
    rangeExtension.forEach((t) => this.select(t));
  }

  private getRangeExtension(target: THREE.Object3D): THREE.Object3D[] {
    const start = this.getSelected(this.selections[0]);
    const range = this.getSelectableRange(start, target);
    return range.filter((t) => !this.isSelected(t));
  }

  private async selectRange(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    if (!this.selections.length) {
      this.selectSingle(target);
      return;
    }

    this.deselectAll(1);
    this.extendSelection(target);
  }

  private getSelectableRange(
    target1: THREE.Object3D,
    target2: THREE.Object3D
  ): THREE.Object3D[] {
    // Try again in order
    if (!this.areInOrder(target1, target2)) {
      return this.getSelectableRange(target2, target1);
    }

    const segmentIndex1 = this.getToolPathSegmentIndex(target1);
    const segmentIndex2 = this.getToolPathSegmentIndex(target2);

    // Try again with propper start
    if (!this.isStateIndicator(target1)) {
      return this.getSelectableRange(
        this.getStateIndicatorOfSegment(segmentIndex1 - 1),
        target2
      );
    }

    // Try again with propper end
    if (!this.isStateIndicator(target2)) {
      return this.getSelectableRange(
        target1,
        this.getStateIndicatorOfSegment(segmentIndex2)
      );
    }

    const segments = this.toolPathSegments.filter(
      (_, i) => i >= segmentIndex1 && i <= segmentIndex2
    );
    const result = [this.getStateIndicatorOfSegment(segmentIndex1)].concat(
      segments.flatMap((t, i) => (i != 0 ? t.meshes : []))
    );
    return result;
  }

  private getStateIndicatorOfSegment(index: number): THREE.Mesh {
    const result = this.toolPathSegments[index].meshes.findLast((t) => t);
    if (result) return result;
    throw new Error('Segment contains no meshes.');
  }

  private isStateIndicator(target: THREE.Object3D): boolean {
    const index = this.getToolPathSegmentIndex(target);
    const segment = this.toolPathSegments[index];
    const subIndex = segment.meshes.findIndex((t) => t.id === target.id);
    return subIndex === segment.meshes.length - 1;
  }

  private areInOrder(
    target1: THREE.Object3D,
    target2: THREE.Object3D
  ): boolean {
    const index1 = this.getToolPathSegmentIndex(target1);
    const index2 = this.getToolPathSegmentIndex(target2);
    if (index1 === index2) {
      const segment = this.toolPathSegments[index1];
      const subIndex1 = segment.meshes.findIndex((t) => t.id === target1.id);
      const subIndex2 = segment.meshes.findIndex((t) => t.id === target2.id);
      return subIndex1 <= subIndex2;
    }
    return index1 < index2;
  }

  private createSelection(target: THREE.Object3D): Selection {
    const segment = this.toolPathSegments.find((t) =>
      t.meshes.some((x) => x.id === target.id)
    );
    if (segment) return { segmentId: segment.segment.id, meshId: target.id };
    throw new Error('Parent segment not found.');
  }

  private getSelected(selection: Selection): THREE.Object3D {
    const result = this.toolPathSegments
      .find((t) => t.segment.id === selection.segmentId)
      ?.meshes.find((t) => t.id === selection.meshId);
    if (result) return result;
    throw new Error('Selected element not found.');
  }

  private getToolPathSegmentIndex(target: THREE.Object3D): number {
    return this.toolPathSegments.findIndex((t) =>
      t.meshes.some((x) => x === target)
    );
  }

  private isSelected(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    return this.selections.some((t) => t.meshId === target.id);
  }

  private isSelectable(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    return this.toolPathSegments.some((t) =>
      t.meshes.some((x) => x.id === target.id)
    );
  }

  private async setHighlightOn(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    const mesh = target as THREE.Mesh;
    if (!mesh.isMesh) {
      return;
    }

    this.materialBackups[mesh.id] = mesh.material;

    const materials = [mesh.material].flatMap((t) => t);
    const isLineMaterial = materials.some(
      (t) => (t as LineMaterial).isLineMaterial
    );
    const isMeshMatcapMaterial = materials.some(
      (t) => (t as THREE.MeshMatcapMaterial).isMeshMatcapMaterial
    );

    if (isLineMaterial) {
      mesh.material = this.lineMaterials.highlightMaterial;
      this.emitChangeEvent(mesh);
    } else if (isMeshMatcapMaterial) {
      mesh.material = await this.highlightMaterial;
      this.emitChangeEvent(mesh);
    }
  }

  private setHighlightOff(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    const mesh = target as THREE.Mesh;
    if (!mesh.isMesh) {
      return;
    }

    mesh.material = this.materialBackups[mesh.id];
    this.emitChangeEvent(mesh);
  }

  private emitChangeEvent(target: THREE.Object3D) {
    if (!this.model) return;
    this.getContainingNode(target, this.model);
    this.model?.observableNode.matrixChange.emit();
  }

  private getContainingNode(
    target: THREE.Object3D,
    node: SceneGraphRendererModelNode
  ): SceneGraphRendererModelNode | undefined {
    if (this.containsObject(target, node.nodeMeshSet)) {
      return node;
    }

    return node.children
      .map((t) => this.getContainingNode(target, t))
      .find((t) => t);
  }

  private containsObject(
    target: THREE.Object3D,
    nodeMeshSet: NodeMeshSet
  ): boolean {
    return this.getAllMeshes(nodeMeshSet).some((t) => t.id === target.id);
  }

  private getAllMeshes(nodeMeshSet: NodeMeshSet): THREE.Mesh[] {
    const toolPathMeshes = nodeMeshSet.toolPath
      ? this.getAllMeshes2(nodeMeshSet.toolPath)
      : [];
    return [...nodeMeshSet.frame, ...nodeMeshSet.geometry, ...toolPathMeshes];
  }

  private getAllMeshes2(toolPathMeshSet: ToolPathMeshSet): THREE.Mesh[] {
    return [
      toolPathMeshSet.directionIndicators,
      ...toolPathMeshSet.segments.flatMap((t) => this.getAllSegmentMeshes(t)),
    ];
  }
}

Could it be due to different Angular version?
The project has Angular version 16.2.12 and the project where the service is, has Angular version 17.3.0.
But I also created a new project with version 16.2.12 where it worked.
What I also should mention is, that there was an error due to incompatible version (so I used --legacy-peer-deps) which made it possible to install.

I guess the problem is not in services or components, but in config files. Try something from this question. I would also suggest removing node_modules folder and package-lock.json, and running npm install again.

Can you please update in your question import { SelectionHelperService } from 'my-external-library'; with the original one which you have used in your project, and also in the service file, use @Injectable instead of Injectable at biggining.

@Tortila That was the issue. But npm install is not possible because that library has a higher Angular version, so I used npm install --legacy-peer-deps and could install the packages but now my project cannot resolve @angular/core, rxjs and so on. Would a solution be to make the library compatible with older versions?
